# Add JSONObject in the for loop to the JSONObject outside

Tags: java, json

I am trying to add all  the JSONobject `arrivals`  in the for loop JSONobject  `stops` outside but I am  always just  getting one `JSONObject` in the `stops`. How can I put all the `arrivales` JSONObject in the for loop in the JSONObject `stops`?

I am using the json library org.json.

I appreciate any help

```
  JSONObject stops = new JSONObject(); 

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();                        
        try {                       
        stops.put("stops_name", key);

        JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();

        JSONArray timeArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
        arrivalMoFr.put( timeArray);

        arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);

        stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);

        System.out.println(stops.toString(3));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the object outside loop and keep adding items in loop. Your arrivals  and arrivalMoFr  are instantiated every time loop runs and you gets the last ites. Try this

```
   JSONObject stops = new JSONObject(); 
   JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
   JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();                        
    try {                       
         stops.put("stops_name", key);



         JSONArray timeArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
         arrivalMoFr.put( timeArray);

         arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);

         stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);

         System.out.println(stops.toString(3));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```